# AngularJs 1.x not updating the visibility of element with ng-show or ng-if either

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show, angularjs-ng-if

I am facing issue with the angular js 1.x not updating the visibility of the element even when variable values are detected. I am using custom angular open-close symbols but I don't see this as an issue.

Here's the sample code:

```
<li ng-if=(( fnc_show_lockin_period_clause() ))></li>
```

where `fnc_show_lockin_period_clause()` is a function in my angular controller.

When the function returns true, the updated html looks like:

```
<li ng-if="true">some content here...</li>
```

and, when the function returns false, the updated html looks like:

```
<li ng-if="false">some content here...</li>
```

Even when the directive is able to identify the value of the variable, it is failing to update the visibility. Exact same thing is happening with the use of ng-show.

Looking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the function is returning the string `"false"` instead of the boolean `false`.

Convert it to a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

If the value is omitted or is `0`, `-0`, `null`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined`, or the empty string (`""`), the expression is `false`. All other values, including any object or the string `"false"`, evaluate as `true`.